# How can I import a typescript-generated module by name from within Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, parceljs

I want to import a function from a typescript-generated module into javascript's global namespace. Here is my typescript module `foo.ts`:

```
export const fooFn = (): string => {
  return "hello";
};
```

Here is my HTML file:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script src="foo.ts"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript">
        window.fooFn = require("./foo.ts").fooFn;
        alert(fooFn());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is giving me the error `Cannot find module './foo.ts'`. After messing around a bit, I've found I can import it using a parcel-generated index (eg, `window.fooFn = require(7).fooFn`) but obviously this is not a workable solution, and the index changes every time I restart the parcel dev server.

So, my question is, how can I import this module by name?

Here is my `tsconfig.json` for reference:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "jsx": "react",
  }
}
```

If you're wondering why I want to expose this function on the global namespace, it's so that I can easily access it from within a WebAssembly application.

Answer (score 0):

This is still an **[unsolved issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13422)**.

Until TypeScript supports a dedicated compilation target you're only options to use a module bundler.

The most popular ones these days are [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), [rollup](https://github.com/rollup/rollup) or [parcel](https://parceljs.org/).

Comment: I am using parcel 